# How can I insert a DecimalFormat in my Java Codes

Tags: java, android, numbers, decimal

how can I insert a DecimalFormat in my Java Codes. I would my value (resultat) like this ###,###,###.00. (Resultat) in result.setText("the rent is " + String.valueOf(resultat) + " currency"); I'm trying several DecimalFormat but without effect, because maybe I don't insert correctly the decimalFormat in the String. Thanks for show me.

```
package albencreation.realestateapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Rent extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText price = null;
    EditText profit = null;
    TextView result = null;
    Button envoyer = null;
    Button close = null;
    Button info = null;
    Button clear = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.rent);

        price = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.price);
        profit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.profit);
        result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
        envoyer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttcalculate);
        close = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttclose);
        info = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttinfo);
        clear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttclear);

        envoyer.setOnClickListener(envoyerListener);
        close.setOnClickListener(closeListener);
        info.setOnClickListener(infoListener);
        clear.setOnClickListener(clearListener);
    }

    private OnClickListener envoyerListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String p = price.getText().toString();
            String o = profit.getText().toString();

            float pValue;
            if (p.isEmpty()) {
                pValue = 0;
            } else {
                pValue = Float.valueOf(p);
            }
            float oValue;
            if (o.isEmpty()) {
                oValue = 0;
            } else {
                oValue = Float.valueOf(o);
            }

            float resultat = oValue * pValue / 100;
            result.setText("the rent is " + String.valueOf(resultat) + " currency");
        }
    };

    private OnClickListener closeListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent jumpage = new Intent(Rent.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(jumpage);
            Rent.this.finish();
        }
    };

    private OnClickListener infoListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent jumpage = new Intent(Rent.this, Inforent.class);
            startActivity(jumpage);
        }
    };

    private OnClickListener clearListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            price.getText().clear();
            profit.getText().clear();
            String defaut = "result rent";
            result.setText(defaut);
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: It's great that you included your code, but `DecimalFormat` does not appear anywhere in the code that you posted. Please see [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the Help Center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formatting properties of `DecimalFormat` with a pattern String.

```
DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###.00");
float resultat = oValue * pValue / 100;
result.setText("the rent is " + myFormatter.format(resultat ) + " currency");
```

This creates a formatter by passing a pattern String to the `DecimalFormat` constructor. The format method accepts a double value as an argument and returns the formatted number in a String.

Comment: Thank you very much, IT WORKS !

Answer (score 0):

```
result.setText("the rent is " + new DecimalFormat("###,###,###.00").format(resultat) + " currency");
```

I get `100,000,000.32` with a value of `100000000.32`

Answer (score 0):

Adding additional `"###,"` is redundant, `###,###.00` will do the job.

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("###,###.00");
```

Comment: Thanks, indeed is redundant.